# Diagonal morphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Hello I'm starting to study algebraic geometry on my own with a book and I've been thinking on this problem a few days. I'd appreciate if someone could help me.

Let $V$ be an affine variety. We define diagonal map as $$\Delta:V\rightarrow \Delta (V)\subset V \times V $$   $$ v\longmapsto(v,v)$$
(a) Prove that $\Delta$ is a morphism.

(b) Let $V=\mathbb{A}^n(k)$ and fixed coordinates $x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_n$ en $\mathbb{A}^n(k)\times \mathbb{A}^n(k)$. Show that $I(\Delta _V)= \langle x_1-y_1,...,x_n-y_n \rangle$.

(c) For general affine variety $V$, prove that $\Delta _V$ is closed in $V \times V$.

(d) Show that $\Delta:V \rightarrow  \Delta _V$ is an isomorphism.

My attemp:

(a) I've proved that statement and I'm sure it's correct.

(b) I can't prove that, I tried many things but  I don't get the solution.

(c) I don't know if this solution it's right.

A topological space $V$ is Hausdorff iff the diagonal set $\Delta _V$ is closed. So if $V$ is an affine variety, and $x,y \in V, x \neq y$. If I consider the lineal polinomial $f $ so that $f(x)=0$, and the paralel lineal polinomial $g$ that anihilates $y$ (It's possible since $x \neq y$), then $U,W$  (subset of points of $V$ such that anihilates f or g, respct.) are disjoint neigbourhoods of $x,y $ and hence, $V$ is Hausdorff.

(d) I've thinked about using projections $\pi_1,\pi_2: V \times V \rightarrow V$, but I didn't get the solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Varieties are not Hausdorff!

Comment: Dear Anthony, you will get more and better  answers if you tell users which book you use, so that they can answer in terms of the relevant section. Else they might use concepts you don't know yet.

Comment: I use : Introduction to algebraic geometry. Brendan Hassett.

Comment: Here are some hints. For (c) and (b) : As Zhen mentioned, varieties are not Hausdorff. But also, the topology on the product is not the product topology. Instead, you should note that the diagonal map comes from a ring homomorphism from $k[V] \otimes_{k} k[V] \rightarrow k[V]$. What is an obvious morphism to use? Then, to check for closedness of the image, just check that the ring homomorphism is surjective.

Comment: Good answer @Siddharth Venkatesh

Comment: For (b), see exercise 2.12 in Hassett. For (c), show $\Delta_{\mathbb A^n}$ is closed, then show $\Delta_V = \Delta_{\mathbb A^n} \cap (V \times V)$. For (d), write down the ring hom from $k[V \times V] \to k[V]$. Is it surjective? What is the kernel? What is $k[V\times V]/\text{kernel}$? Is it $k[\Delta_V]$? What can you conclude from the first isomorphism theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) The map is by definition the one induced from $ A \otimes_k A \to A$ and so is a morphism (by definition of a morphism of schemes). Here I am thinking of $A$ as $\Gamma(V,\mathcal{O}_V)$.

(b) If $V = \Bbb{A}^n$ then the diagonal map is coming from $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\otimes_k  k[y_1,\ldots,y_n] \to k[t_1,\ldots,t_n]$ where we send $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\otimes g(y_1,\ldots,y_n) \mapsto f(t_1,\ldots,t_n)g(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$. The kernel is generated by $x_i \otimes 1 - 1\otimes y_i$.

(c) The ring map $A \otimes_k A \to A$ is surjective and so the map on Spec has to be a closed immersion.

(d) A closed immersion is also an isomorphism onto its image.

Comment: Fantastic answer.